# std::get using enum class as template argument

Tags: c++, get, c++11, tuples, enum-class

I'm using a `std::tuple` and defined a class enum to somehow "naming" each of the tuple's fields, forgetting about their actual indexes.

So instead of doing this:

```
std::tuple<A,B> tup;
/* ... */
std::get<0>(tup) = bleh; // was it 0, or 1?
```

I did this:

```
enum class Something {
     MY_INDEX_NAME = 0,
     OTHER_INDEX_NAME
};

std::tuple<A,B> tup;
/* ... */
std::get<Something::MY_INDEX_NAME> = 0; // I don't mind the actual index...
```

The problem is that, as this compiled using gcc 4.5.2, I've now installed the 4.6.1 version, and my project failed to compile. This snippet reproduces the error:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

enum class Bad {
    BAD = 0
};

enum Good {
    GOOD = 0
};

int main() {
    std::tuple<int, int> tup(1, 10);
    std::cout << std::get<0>(tup) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<GOOD>(tup) << std::endl; // It's OK
    std::cout << std::get<Bad::BAD>(tup) << std::endl; // NOT!
}
```

The error basically says that there's no overload that matches my call to `std::get`:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:16:40: error: no matching function for call to ‘get(std::tuple<int, int>&)’
test.cpp:16:40: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/utility:133:5: note: template<unsigned int _Int, class _Tp1, class _Tp2> typename std::tuple_element<_Int, std::pair<_Tp1, _Tp2> >::type& std::get(std::pair<_Tp1, _Tp2>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/utility:138:5: note: template<unsigned int _Int, class _Tp1, class _Tp2> const typename std::tuple_element<_Int, std::pair<_Tp1, _Tp2> >::type& std::get(const std::pair<_Tp1, _Tp2>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/tuple:531:5: note: template<unsigned int __i, class ... _Elements> typename std::__add_ref<typename std::tuple_element<__i, std::tuple<_Elements ...> >::type>::type std::get(std::tuple<_Elements ...>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/tuple:538:5: note: template<unsigned int __i, class ... _Elements> typename std::__add_c_ref<typename std::tuple_element<__i, std::tuple<_Elements ...> >::type>::type std::get(const std::tuple<_Elements ...>&)
```

So, is there any way I can use my enum class as a template argument to `std::get`? Was this something that wasn't ment to compile, and was fixed in gcc 4.6? I could use a simple enum, but I like the scoping properties of enum classes, so I'd prefer to use the latter if it's possible.

Comment: If you put an unscoped enum into a struct then you get a type that doesn't pollute the namespace it's in and that can be implicitly converted to whatever type `std::get` needs: `struct foo { enum { bar }; };` and then `std::get<foo::bar>(baz)`. (However none of the enumerators can have the same name as the struct they're in.)

Comment: Just to say, "namespace" has been added to plain old enums too, so basically, you'll be able to write Good::GOOD if it's somehow why you wanted to use enum class instead of enum.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The strongly-typed enums introduced by C++11 cannot be implicitly converted into integral values of type say `int`, while `std::get` expects the template argument to be integral type.

You've to use `static_cast` to convert the enum values:

```
std::cout <<std::get<static_cast<int>(Bad::BAD)>(tup)<< std::endl; //Ok now!
```

Or you can choose to convert into underlying integral type as:

```
//note that it is constexpr function
template <typename T>
constexpr typename std::underlying_type<T>::type integral(T value) 
{
    return static_cast<typename std::underlying_type<T>::type>(value);
}
```

then use it as:

```
std::cout <<std::get<integral(Bad::BAD)>(tup)<< std::endl; //Ok now!
```

Comment: I'll use plain enums, but I like your solution.

Comment: Why not rename your `integral` function to `enum_cast`?

Comment: @rhalbersma: If I rename `integral` to `enum_cast`, then the usage will still be `enum_cast(Bad::BAD)` which doesn't look like a *cast*, as a *cast* usually takes the form of `enum_cast<T>(Bad::BAD)`. So the *cast-form* doesn't fit in this case.

Comment: ah, good point, I had forgotten about the explicit template argument. In any case, if I have a class with only a `std::tuple` member named `data_`, then I'd combine your solution with @Jonathan Wakely's and use an old-school anonymous `enum { name1_, name2_, ..., nameN_ };` and then do something like `Ret_type1& name1() { return std::get<name1_>(data_) }`. With this underscore convention, even the old enum will not cause name clashes inside the class.

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to add another answer because the original poster asked for a way to have a named access to elements of std::tuple through a class enum.

It is possible to have a template argument of the type of a class enum (at least in GCC). This makes it possible to define your own `get` retrieving the element of a tuple given a class enum value. Below is an implementation casting this value to int, but you could also do something more fancy:

```
#include <tuple>

enum class names { A = 0, B, C };

template< names n, class... Types >
typename std::tuple_element<static_cast< std::size_t >( n ), std::tuple<Types...> >::type&
    get( std::tuple<Types...>& t )
{
    return std::get< static_cast< std::size_t >( n ), Types... >( t );
}

int main( int, char** )
{
    std::tuple< char, char, char > t( 'a', 'b', 'c' );
    char c = get<names::A>( t );
}
```

Note that [`std::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) has two more variants (one for `const tuple&`, one for `tuple&&`), which can be implemented exactly the same way.

Comment: thanks very usefull +1. I was searchin for a way to specialize templates based on enum value and this is a good start.

Comment: You can also make your `std::get` argument generic by using a universal reference and then SFINAE when `is_tuple<std::remove_cvref_t<Tuple>>`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this was a bug in GCC 4.5. Scoped enums don't have implicit conversions to integral types.

Comment: Meh, then i'll go back to plain old enums.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I was thinking of a generic solution that would let you keep the same syntax.

Answer (score 2):

A completely different solution would be:

```
A& my_field(std::tuple<A,B>& t) { return std::get<0>(t); }
A const& my_field(std::tuple<A,B> const& t) { return std::get<0>(t); }

B& my_other_field(std::tuple<A,B>& t) { return std::get<1>(t); }
B const& my_other_field(std::tuple<A,B> const& t) { return std::get<1>(t); }

my_field(t) = blah;
my_other_field(t) = frob;
```

Answer (score 0):

2018 update:

It's not a problem anymore. I did have a problem when I tried variations of "enum class int", but this now works fine with VS 2017 15.7.2

```
enum 
{
  WIDTH,
  HEIGHT
};
std::get<HEIGHT>( Remaining ) = std::get<HEIGHT>( Remaining ) - MinHeight;
```

Comment: the question specifically asks how to make this work for `enum class`

Comment: std::get in C++ 17 can handle 

`enum MyType : std::size_t {  Width, Height};`

It would be nice if std::get<...> would also support `enum class`.

Answer (score -1):

My solution is to use:

```
namespace Something{enum class Something {MY_INDEX_NAME = 0,OTHER_INDEX_NAME};};
```