# typedef for function template (partial instantiation)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, tuples, template-meta-programming

Sorry I didn't really know how to call my question, hope it fits...

I have a function template which gets an argument as template parameter. For that argument I need to have another template parameter which declares the type of the argument but while calling that function later on, I would like to omit the type of the argument. So, I would like to have some kind of typedef (or other mechanism) to get rid of it.

I've seen a similar mechnism with other templates, e.g.

```
// given: rule is a template with three arguments
template<typename Attr> using Rule = rule<It, Attr(), Skipper>;
```

When using `std::get` one can get along without mentioning the enum class directly:

```
std::get<static_cast<std::size_t>(Enum::type1)>(tuple);
```

Here is the function, it is used to access a tuple with an enum (compare: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14835597/2524462)

```
template<typename Enum, Enum enum, class ... Types>
typename std::tuple_element<static_cast<std::size_t>(enum), std::tuple<Types...> >::type&
get(std::tuple<Types...>& t) {
  return std::get<static_cast<std::size_t>(enum)>(t);
}
```

Since it will be used with several enums, I don't want to hardwire the enum in the template like he did.

It is called like: (1)

```
std::cout << get<myEnum, myEnum::type1>(tuple);
```

Questions:

- Can I use a typedef or similar to call it just like:

  ```
  std::cout << new_get < myEnum::type1 > (tuple);
  ```
- Since it works with std::get, is there a way to have a smarter template, in the first place?
- The get template here has the tuple types as last parameters. Why is it not necessary to spell them out here (1)? How does the compiler figure them out from the given parameter?

I'm using gcc 4.8.1 with C++11 enabled.

Comment: Use default arguments maybe?

Comment: Could this question be simplified? Could you just say what you currently have (working) and how you would like it to be?

Comment: The template like stated here works. It is called like in (1), which I find too verbose. I would like to call it like spelled out in my first question.

Comment: This isn't possible, for similar reasons to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11745764/951890

Comment: @VaughnCato: when using: "std::get<static_cast<std::size_t>(Enum::type1)>(tuple);" It works without spelling out the enum directly, so there is a way...

Comment: I don't understand your logic.  As I understand it, you are wanting to achieve a particular syntax.  Just because you can get a certain result using one syntax doesn't imply you can get that same result using a different syntax.

Comment: @VaughnCato Well yes, that's my goal. I want to wrap that little std::get call in something nicer. Why, because I want a clean interface in my project. I still hope, that C++11 can be pretty, too ;-) So for me nice possibilities would be "get(myEnum::type1, tuple)" or "tuple.get(myEnum::type1)".

Comment: Can you associate particular enums with particular tuple types?  If so, you might just want to overload your `get<>` template for the various tuple types.

Comment: @VaughnCato: Yes, the tuples know, to which enum they are associated. Not the other way round, since there may be several tuples for each enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best you are going to be able to do is to create a `get<>()` function for each enumeration.  Here is an example:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::tuple<std::string,std::string> Tuple1;
typedef std::tuple<std::string,int> Tuple2;

enum class Enum1 {
  name,
  address
};

enum class Enum2 {
  state,
  zip_code
};

template <typename Enum>
constexpr std::size_t indexOf(Enum value)
{
  return static_cast<std::size_t>(value);
}

template <typename Enum,Enum enum_value,typename Tuple>
constexpr auto get(const Tuple &value)
  -> decltype(std::get<indexOf(enum_value)>(value))
{
  return std::get<indexOf(enum_value)>(value);
}

template <Enum1 enum_value>
constexpr auto get(const Tuple1 &value)
  -> decltype(get<Enum1,enum_value>(value))
{
  return get<Enum1,enum_value>(value);
}

template <Enum2 enum_value>
constexpr auto get(const Tuple2 &value)
  -> decltype(get<Enum2,enum_value>(value))
{
  return get<Enum2,enum_value>(value);
}

int main(int,char**)
{
  Tuple1 a("John","123 Foo St");
  Tuple2 b("California",90210);
  std::cerr << get<Enum1::name>(a) << "\n";
  std::cerr << get<Enum1::address>(a) << "\n";
  std::cerr << get<Enum2::state>(b) << "\n";
  std::cerr << get<Enum2::zip_code>(b) << "\n";
}
```

It is tedious, however this does have the benefit of compile-time checking that the enumerations are compatible with the tuples.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I was hoping to get around the explicit instantiation for Enum1 and Enum2. What I still don't get is, why         template <typename Enum, typename Tuple>
         constexpr auto get(Enum enum_value, const Tuple &value)
          -> decltype(std::get<indexOf(enum_value)>(value))
is not possible (use of parameter 'enum_value' outside function body) but template <class T, class U>
auto add(T t, U u) -> decltype(t + u); is ok.

Comment: @MikeM: In the case of `template <class T,class U> auto add(T t,U u) -> decltype(t+u)`, the return type of the function only depends on the types of the arguments, which are known at compile time.  In the case of `template <typename Enum,typename Tuple> constexpr auto get(Enum enum_value,const Tuple &value) -> decltype(std::get<indexOf(enum_value)>(value))`, the return type depends on the value of the argument, which is not known at compile time (in general).

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I see the difference. So, one would need something like constexpr for parameters? I'm tring to wrap my head about the underlying rules. I just found out, that while your indexOf works fine, this doesn't work `template<typename Enum> struct Test{Test(Enum value) {...}}` and calling it `Test(myEnum::type1);` Well, still learning. Thank you for your efforts.