# Compile time access to tuple item with an enum value

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2013, tuples, decltype, trailing-return-type

I would like to use enum values as index to access to tuple items. I've read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742275/stdget-using-enum-class-as-template-argument) to help.
I'm working in VS2013 thus I cannot use C++14 very handy `auto` without `trailing return`.
Static cast works but it's cumbersome, also it requires tuple is freely accessed (in real code attributes are in `protected` scope).
I want to improve this by using a templated method `GetAttribute`.
I tried this but it produces an error:

> prog.cpp:30:119: error: invalid operands of types '' and 'size_t {aka unsigned int}' to binary 'operator<'
>        auto GetAttribute(AttributeName attributeName) -> decltype(std::declval(std::get(attributeName)>(attributes)))
>                                                                                                                          ^
>   prog.cpp:30:119: error: invalid operands of types '' and 'size_t {aka unsigned int}' to binary 'operator<'
>   prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>   prog.cpp:57:4: error: 'struct X' has no member named 'GetAttribute'
>     x.GetAttribute(XParameters::PARAMETER1); // Does not compile.
>       ^

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/QgxBph)

```
#include <tuple>
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

enum class XParameters : unsigned int
{
    PARAMETER1, // int
    PARAMETER2, // float
    MAX,
};

enum class YParameters : unsigned int
{
    PARAMETER3 = XParameters::MAX // std::string
};

using XTuple = std::tuple<int, float>;
using YAttributes = std::tuple<std::string>;
using YTuple = decltype(tuple_cat(XTuple(), YAttributes()));

template <typename Attributes>
struct Common
{
    Common(Attributes&& attr) : attributes(std::move(attr)) {}

    Attributes attributes;

    template <typename AttributeName>
    auto GetAttribute(AttributeName attributeName) -> decltype(std::declval(std::get<static_cast<size_t>(attributeName)>(attributes)))
    {
        return std::get<static_cast<size_t>(attributeName)>(attributes);
    }
};

struct X : Common<XTuple>
{
    X() : Common(std::make_tuple(42, 3.14f)) {}
};

struct Y : Common<YTuple>
{
    Y() : Common(std::make_tuple(666, 0.01f, "string")) {}
};

int main()
{
    X x;
    Y y;

    int parameter1 = std::get<static_cast<size_t>(XParameters::PARAMETER1)>(x.attributes); // Compiles, works.
    std::cout << parameter1 << std::endl;

    std::string parameter3 = std::get<static_cast<size_t>(YParameters::PARAMETER3)>(y.attributes); // Compiles, works.
    std::cout << parameter3 << std::endl;

    // Shorter code
    x.GetAttribute(XParameters::PARAMETER1); // Does not compile.

    //parameter3 = std::get<static_cast<size_t>(YParameters::PARAMETER3)>(x.attributes); // Does not compile, phew...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How should the compiler convert the runtime value `attributeName` to a compile time value for `std::get`'s template parameter in the `static_cast`?

Comment: `attributeName` value is known at compile time, it's equal to `XParameters::PARAMETER1` for `x.GetAttribute(XParameters::PARAMETER1);` instruction.

Comment: It is known at the call site at compile time but it is a normal function call so inside the `GetAttribute` function it is a runtime parameter. If available you can test that with `static_assert(XParameters::PARAMETER1 == attributeName, "");` which should tell you that `attributeName` is not a compile time value.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion to fix this ?

Comment: Btw.: Why do you use declval in the decltype? What is the use of `struct Common`? (You could achieve the same with a free function and raw `std::tuple`s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid there will be no pretty solution.

### Ugly variant - Cast at call site

The easiest way to achieve something similar would be to pass the value as a non-type template parameter:

```
template <size_t attributeName>
auto GetAttribute() -> decltype(std::get<attributeName>(attributes))
{
    return std::get<attributeName>(attributes);
}
```

This would make the call ugly because you would have to do the cast there:

```
x.GetAttribute<static_cast<size_t>(XParameters::PARAMETER1)>();
```

### Not so ugly variant - associated enum type

You could work around that by associating an enum type with the Common class like this:

```
template <typename Attributes, typename EnumType>
struct Common
{
    Common(Attributes&& attr) : attributes(std::move(attr)) {}

    Attributes attributes;

    template <size_t attributeName>
    auto GetAttribute() -> decltype(std::get<attributeName>(attributes))
    {
        return std::get<attributeName>(attributes);
    }

    template <EnumType attributeName>
    auto GetAttribute() -> decltype(GetAttribute<static_cast<size_t>(attributeName)>())
    {
        return GetAttribute<static_cast<size_t>(attributeName)>();
    }

};
```

Which would allow for calling like that:

```
struct X : Common<XTuple, XParameters>
{
    X() : Common(std::make_tuple(42, 3.14f)) {}
};

x.GetAttribute<XParameters::PARAMETER1>();
```

Obviously, you would need to dedicated an enum for each Common instance.

### Best variant(?) - Free (overloaded) function

In this case you just use raw tuples. Then you roll your own function (e.g. `GetAttribute`) that you overload for your specific type of tuple and enum:

```
template <XParameters attributeName>
auto GetAttribute(XTuple &tuple) -> decltype(std::get<static_cast<size_t>(attributeName)>(tuple) )
{
    return  std::get<static_cast<size_t>(attributeName)>(tuple);
}

GetAttribute<XParameters::PARAMETER1>(x.attributes);
```

Defining `GetAttribute` in this case has a lot of boilerplate code so you might want to hide it behind a macro:

```
#define DEFINE_GetAttribute(ENUM_TYPE, TUPLE_TYPE)                             \
  template <ENUM_TYPE attributeName>                                           \
  auto GetAttribute(TUPLE_TYPE &tuple)                                         \
      ->decltype(std::get<static_cast<size_t>(attributeName)>(tuple)) {        \
    return std::get<static_cast<size_t>(attributeName)>(tuple);                \
  }

DEFINE_GetAttribute(XParameters, XTuple)
```